# How to prevent the compiler from optimizing out reads

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

I am writing a Rust application for the ESP32-S3 microcontroller and trying to get ESPNow (connectionless WiFi protocol) setup.
In the EspNow rust wrapper [API](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_svc/espnow/struct.EspNow.html), you have to provide a receive callback to receive packets, like this:

```rust
self.espnow_driver
    .register_recv_cb(|_info: &[u8], bytes: &[u8]| {
        match Packet::deserialize_from(bytes) {
            Ok(p) => self.received_packets.push_back(p),
            Err(e) => log::warn!("Could not decode received packet: {}", e),
        };
     })
     .unwrap();
```

I want the calling code to be able to process packets at its own rate, so I just put the received packet into a `VecDeque` for later processing.
Then I have another function for the calling code to use:

```rust
fn receive(&mut self) -> Option<Packet> {
   return self.received_packets.pop_front();
}
```

The problem is, that `receive` always returns `None`, even if packets are inserted into the queue.
I checked that insertion works by just printing the queue inside the `register_recv_cb` closure.
My guess is that the compiler optimizes out the read inside `receive`, because the reception callback closure is only executed when an interrupt occurs.
So the compiler just assumes that the queue is not written to after initialization and can optimize out the read.

How can I prevent this from happening? I already tried to use `core::hint::black_box` and `std::ptr::read_volatile` around the `pop_front` call, but that did not change anything.
I looked online and there don't seem to be many low-level options to deal with something like this in Rust.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Note, in Rust you can switch from `return X;` to `X` if this is the last statement.

Comment: That's a theory you can validate by adding some tracing statements in there.

Comment: If this behavior is from the reason you think it is, then Rusts aliasing rules must have been violated. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: See the first point of the [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) docs: As long as a `&mut Self` exists (`.push_back()` needs it to exist), the compiler *will* assume that `Self` can't change. While `UnsafeCell` is in no way the same as (ugh) `volatile` (ugh), you'll need to wrap whatever the interrupt-handler changes into an `UnsafeCell`, probably by means of a `RefCell`. If interrupts can happen at any time, including while the queue is being drawn from, you'll probably want a `Mutex` anyway.

Comment: Seems like the `register_recv_cb` API is unsound if it allows this kind of thing. I would recommend trying to put the `VecDeque` inside a `Mutex`.

Comment: Seems like the closure bound should be `Fn` instead of `FnMut`

Comment: Yes `register_recv_cb` calls `core::mem::transmute(callback)` internally, which as far as I understand throws all safety guarantees out the window. I'm not sure about using a Mutex. If I take the Mutex inside `receive` and then receive a packet immediately after, would I then need to drop the packet? Because the mutex is still taken inside `receive`.

Comment: Change `received_packets` to `Mutex<VecDeque<Packet>>`. Change `self.received_packets.push_back(p)` to `self.received_packets.lock().push_back(p)`. Change `self.received_packets.pop_front()` to `self.received_packets.lock().pop_front()`

Comment: For now I have gotten it to work by using a mpsc queue instead of a `VecDeque`, but I am not sure if that approach is correct.

Comment: Oh, and change `fn receive(&mut self)` to `fn receive(&self)`

Comment: What is the type of `self.received_packets`? I don't think it's just a naked `VecDeque`? I suspect the closure is not actually capturing a mutable reference to the `VecDeque`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to mutably borrow it in `recieve()` later.

You are effectively trying to hand out two mutable references to a VecDeque, since that's not actually possible, I think something else is going on (perhaps the closure is mutating a copy?).

Comment: Using a standard tool like an MPSC (or SPSC) queue is the right approach. You need a data structure capable of handling the idea that two different threads (or ISRs) may push/pop to the queue at any time, and is capable of synchronizing those accesses.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your code (or a minimal reproducible example), to determine if the soundness bug is in your code or in the ESP crates, which should be reported upstream.